# How do I add sudo permissions to a user created with Ansible?

Tags: ansible

What is the cleanest way of doing this? Tried adding the user to the sudo group with the users module but Ansible reports it can't find the sudo group.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of

```
- name: create a new user
    user: name=user
          state=present
          groups="group1, group2"
          password={{ password }}
          comment="Comment"
```

I did

```
- name: create a new user
    user: name=user
          state=present
          group=primary-group
          groups="sudo"
          password={{ password }}
          comment="Comment"
```

And the user was added to the sudo group.

Comment: ```groups="www, sudo"``` msg: Group  sudo does not exist, on ubuntu 14

Comment: You probably want the 'wheel' group

Comment: Setting a password should be a last resort - better to use keys only.

Comment: Is the intention that once this task is run, all other playbook tasks are executed as 'user' user?

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 9):

```
- name: Create Deploy user
  user: name={{ deploy }} comment="Deploy User" groups="sudo,admin,{{ deploy }}"
  sudo: yes
```

Be careful of spaces in your groups list... You get the "group does not exist" if you have them.

Answer (score 1):

groups="admin" will create user add in admin groups

Comment: in which os? "Group  admin does not exist" on ubuntu 1404

Answer (score 1):

To do it in a traditional linux way using ansible :)

Make a file, `create_user.yml` and add the following code.
Change `<username>` with the username you want to add to the sudo group

```
- name: "run command"
  become: true
  gather_facts: no
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: add user to sudo group
      shell: usermod -aG sudo <username>
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
```

Now run this user_create.yml playbook with the command

```
ansible-playbook -K <filename>.yml
```